# Eclipse "Undefined CSS class" how to include online CSS? (not IGNORE)

Tags: css, eclipse

I'm creating an HTML file in Eclipse with a link to an online css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
```

My class attributes are highlighted in yellow with the "Undefined CSS class" warning. How do I tell eclipse to validate it properly?

I have tried Preferences -> Web -> HTML Files -> Web Resources -> Validate External URL (check) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Got the same issue. It wasn't there at the start but popped-up after I installed an AngularJS plugin. In the end I ended up in disabling CSS class validation since it just does not go away.